# Counting the number of days in specific months from date range. Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, transpose, flatten

I am trying to make a google sheet where it will automatically calculate how many days a device was in repair per month.

I need it to calculate the dates in columns and to post the results in a different column rows since there will be a list which will constantly have new entries

Ex:

```
Device| start date | end date.

Laptop| 8/29/2021 | 9/10/2021. 2 days in August,  10 days in September
```

The desired result would it be in 2 columns 1 for month 1, column 2 for month 2

I managed to find this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({EOMONTH(row(indirect("A"&A2):indirect("A"&B2)),0),row(indirect("A"&A2):indirect("A"&B2))},"Select Col1,Count(Col2) group by Col1 label Col1 'Month', count(Col2)'Days in Month' format Col1 'MMMM-YYYY' "))
```

but I cannot use it in a list sheet. Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF((A1:A="")+(B1:B=""),,
 IF(C1:C-B1:B>=SEQUENCE(1, MAX(C1:C-B1:B), ), 
 ROW(A1:A)&"×"&TEXT((B1:B)+SEQUENCE(1, MAX(C1:C-B1:B), ), "mm"), ))), "×")), 
 "select count(Col1) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"), "offset 1", 0)),,9^9)), " "))
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IxOqBP8LoisR_XgIDPMtHXzvy9-XANhbfc9DgMYaEkg/edit#gid=1471587132)

Comment: IT WORKS. I LOVE YOU SO MUCH. GOD BLESS YOU.  It took me so much time and i kept hittin dead ends

Comment: @Danion add `yyyy` if you want to differentiate between years too: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnAzH.png

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is easiest to do by using `sequence()` to enumerate the dates, format them as month names only with `text()`, and aggregate the data with `query()`, following with some string manipulation to split the data into columns, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    isdate(B2) * isdate(C2), 
    split( 
      regexreplace( 
        join( 
          "", 
          flatten( 
            query( 
              " days in " & text(sequence(C2 - B2 + 1, 1, B2), "mmµmmmm→"), 
              "select count(Col1), Col1 group by Col1 label count(Col1) '' ", 
              0 
            ) 
          )  
        ), 
        "\d+µ", "" 
      ), 
      "→" 
    ), 
    iferror(1/0) 
  ) 
)
```

This formula will handle dates that span multiple months, giving as many columns as there are months in the period.

Comment: At the moment I'm am wracking my head into making  a really  long IF formula. But my brain ain't  too good. I am not too familiar with arrays and queries. So i can't really see how it would work with your idea. I really appreciate your input. Your's solution looks way better than what my monkey brain was able to scramble.

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data.

Comment: A good idea. When i will be at the pc i will be able to link it

Answer (score 1):

If you can have one formula for each month, then this will work.

Your use case only calls for two months.  If the repair can span 3 months, how would you like that to be displayed?

**FIRST OUTPUT COLUMN**

In your example, column B would be the start date and column D would be the output:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(Month(B2:B) = Month(C2:C), 
    C2:C - B2:B + 1
      & IF(C2:C - B2:B +1 = 1, " day in ", " days in ") 
      & Text(B2:B, "mmmm"),
    EOMONTH(B2:B, 0)-B2:B + 1 
      & IF(EOMONTH(B2:B, 0)-B2:B+1 = 1, " day in ", " days in ") 
      & Text(B2:B, "mmmm")
  )
)
```

Explanation  -  First we check if the start and end date are in the same month.  If they are, it is the concatenation of the difference + 1, your text, and the month as below.

`EOMONTH()` Gives you the last date of the selected month.  So this works by getting the last day of the month, subtracting the start date giving you the number of days for that month.

To get the text word value of a month, you use the `TEXT()` function to convert the data into a month.  'mmmm' gives August, 'mmm' gives you Aug, and 'mm' returns the number of the month.
The if statement in the middle corrects for the grammar difference of 1 day vs 3 days.

Then you concatenate those together with the 'days in' text, and wrap it in a `ARRAYFORMULA()`.

**SECOND OUTPUT COLUMN**

Similar to the first, but the math is a bit different.

```
=Arrayformula(
  IF(Month(B2:B) = Month(C2:C),
   "", 
   Text(C2:C, "dd") 
    & IF( Text(C2:C, "dd") = 1, " day in ", " days in ") 
    & Text(C2:C, "mmmm")
   )
)
```

Explanation  -  First we check if the start and finish are in the same month, if they are, then this month is blank.  If you would rather have 0 days, you can adjust to show that.

Here you get the number day of the month.  Since the number of days in September is equal to the date.  So, you get the number of the month using TEXT() and 'dd', and concatenate it with your text and the month's text value.

[image]

Comment: There's a one-off error in the first formula — if the start date is 31 August, it will get "0 days in August". The second formula will only report the days in the final month, ignoring other months in dates that span three months or more.

Comment: Good point.   Let me fix.

Comment: The OP only asked for two columns for two months.  If there are 3 months, we need to know how he wants that displayed.  All concatenated into the second column, in a third column, etc?

Comment: Op here. I just want to count the days in cases where the period of the days the device was in repairs so i could count how many total days in that month were in repairs. And i need to do it automatically for each month. I will try to provide a test file in a bit

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used. A32 contains the month you are interested in and when you copy down the formula to other months that will change. In my case what I needed was the rate that applied for the days on the specified month in each range and the rate was tied to the range in question. Hence for each range if it matched the month on the row I needed to aggregate the product and spit out a final aggregated value for the month :

=SUMPRODUCT(Rates,
IFS(
MONTH(A32)<MONTH(StartDates),0,
MONTH(A32)=MONTH(StartDates),DAYS(IFS(EOMONTH(A32,0)=EndDates, EndDates,EOMONTH(A32,0)<EndDates,EOMONTH(A32,0),EOMONTH(A32,0)>EndDates,EndDates),StartDates)+IF(EndDates>EOMONTH(A32,0),1,0),
MONTH(A32)>MONTH(StartDates), IF(MONTH(A32)<=MONTH(EndDates), DAYS(IFS(EOMONTH(A32,0)=EndDates, EndDates,EOMONTH(A32,0)<EndDates,EOMONTH(A32,0),EOMONTH(A32,0)>EndDates,EndDates),
IFS(StartDates=A32, StartDates,StartDates<A32,A32,StartDates>A32,StartDates)
)+IF(EndDates>EOMONTH(A32,0),1,0),0)
)
)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).